# ERROR: java.io.IOException: Table Namespace Manager not ready yet, try again later

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm using HDP2 platform. While working with HBase.I'm trying to create table in hbase. Below is command i'm using.

hbase(main):002:0> create 'test','cf1','cf2'

But It gives me below error

```
ERROR: java.io.IOException: Table Namespace Manager not ready yet, try again later
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.getNamespaceDescriptor(HMaster.java:3328)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1911)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java:40470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2078)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FifoRpcScheduler$1.run(FifoRpcScheduler.java:74)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Here is some help for this command:
Creates a table. Pass a table name, and a set of column family
specifications (at least one), and, optionally, table configuration.
Column specification can be a simple string (name), or a dictionary
(dictionaries are described below in main help output), necessarily
including NAME attribute.
Examples:

Create a table with namespace=ns1 and table qualifier=t1
  hbase> create 'ns1:t1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 5}

Create a table with namespace=default and table qualifier=t1
  hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1'}, {NAME => 'f2'}, {NAME => 'f3'}
  hbase> # The above in shorthand would be the following:
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'
  hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 1, TTL => 2592000, BLOCKCACHE => true}
  hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', CONFIGURATION => {'hbase.hstore.blockingStoreFiles' => '10'}}

Table configuration options can be put at the end.
Examples:

  hbase> create 'ns1:t1', 'f1', SPLITS => ['10', '20', '30', '40']
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', SPLITS => ['10', '20', '30', '40']
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', SPLITS_FILE => 'splits.txt', OWNER => 'johndoe'
  hbase> create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 5}, METADATA => { 'mykey' => 'myvalue' }
  hbase> # Optionally pre-split the table into NUMREGIONS, using
  hbase> # SPLITALGO ("HexStringSplit", "UniformSplit" or classname)
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', {NUMREGIONS => 15, SPLITALGO => 'HexStringSplit'}
  hbase> create 't1', 'f1', {NUMREGIONS => 15, SPLITALGO => 'HexStringSplit', REGION_REPLICATION => 2, CONFIGURATION => {'hbase.hregion.scan.loadColumnFamiliesOnDemand'
 => 'true'}}

You can also keep around a reference to the created table:

  hbase> t1 = create 't1', 'f1'

Which gives you a reference to the table named 't1', on which you can then
call methods
```

.

Below is my hbase-site.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright 2010 The Apache Software Foundation
 *
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
-->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://severname:8020/apps/hbase/data</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>my_server_name</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.log.dir</name>
    <value>d:\hadoop\logs\hbase</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.wal.codec</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.IndexedWALEditCodec</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**Please help me to resolve this.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually after investigating region server log files. I've understand the problem. The problem was

```
2015-03-12 18:10:27,718 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Last block locations not available. Datanodes might not have reported blocks completely. Will retry for 1 times
2015-03-12 18:10:31,720 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogFactory: Can't open after 24 attempts and 310413ms  for hdfs://server_name(name_node):8020/apps/hbase/data/WALs/region_server1,60020,1424845883415-splitting/region_server1%2C60020%2C1424845883415.1424856732238
2015-03-12 18:10:31,720 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter: Processed 0 edits across 0 regions; log file=hdfs://server_name(namenode):8020/apps/hbase/data/WALs/region_server160020,1424845883415-splitting/region_server1%2C60020%2C1424845883415.1424856732238 is corrupted = false progress failed = false
2015-03-12 18:10:31,720 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.SplitLogWorker: log splitting of WALs/region_server1,60020,1424845883415-splitting/region_server1%2C60020%2C1424845883415.1424856732238 failed, returning error
java.io.IOException: Could not obtain the last block locations.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogFactory.createReader(HLogFactory.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogFactory.createReader(HLogFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter.getReader(HLogSplitter.java:639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter.getReader(HLogSplitter.java:564)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter.splitLogFile(HLogSplitter.java:277)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.HLogSplitter.splitLogFile(HLogSplitter.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.SplitLogWorker$1.exec(SplitLogWorker.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.handler.HLogSplitterHandler.process(HLogSplitterHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.EventHandler.run(EventHandler.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So, I tried some file system check for HBase

**hbase hbck**

It shows me 2 inconsistencies

Then I fix issue by using **hbase hbck -fix** commands